# “machen anzufangen” vs. “anfangen zu machen”

Tags: verb, particle, infinitive

I was sure that

> Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgabe machen anzufangen.

was right. Nevertheless I’ve heard

> Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgabe anfangen zu machen.

from a good source.

- Assuming that one is wrong, which is the right one?
- If both are right, do they differ by meaning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both are wrong. It is „vorhaben, etwas zu tun“, so the „anfangen“ needs a „zu“, which is why the second variant is wrong. So we are at

> Ich habe vor, […] anzufangen.

Next, it is „anfangen, etwas zu tun“, so again the „die Hausaufgaben machen“ needs a „zu“:

> Ich habe vor, anzufangen, die Hausaufgaben zu machen.

Now German is somewhat liberal regarding word order, and

> Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgaben zu machen anzufangen.

is also ok.

Now this is a bit complicated, one might want to avoid the „machen“ altogether:

> Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgaben anzufangen.

Comment: There are many possible variations. Personally, I'd prefer: _Ich habe vor, mit der Hausaufgabe anzufangen._

Comment: Yes, that is also what I would say. Just when I wanted to write it down I was not so sure anymore.

Comment: ach so. Ich habe einen ,,zu" vergessen.

Comment: Genau, ein(!) „zu“ hattest Du vergessen ;)

Comment: Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgaben zu machen anzufangen... I wouldn'T call this correct. Technically it might be. However, the sentence sounds grammatically and semantically concluded after "zu machen". Habe vor has it's complement and so does "machen". hence, our brain is done processing and ready for a new sentence and only then the second, the real compliment comes and we have to reevaluate everything (grammar, meaning) .And while this might sometimes be desirable for stylistic reasons, here it is  even made worse by the double zu back to back "zu machen anzufangen". This sounds bad. So: not ok

Comment: @Emanuel I would say that "technically correct" is the only thing that counts. Just because nobody uses the phrase like that, doesn't mean it is not ok. Had he used *Ich habe vor anzufangen, die Hausaufgaben zu machen* you wouldn't have complained, right?

Comment: @Torsten Dittmar: I disagree. A lot of things are technically correct and still would be edited out by a copy editor or marked as bad style in school. This is a very clear example. In my opinion it is in no situation acceptable to phrase it that way although grammatically it is "possible". And yes, I wouldn't have complained because all the reasons I state in my comment do NOT apply to the alternative you suggested.

Comment: @Emanuel, yes, „Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgaben zu machen anzufangen.“ might not be the best choice stylistically, which is why I put the other word order first. But note that the intonation of „machen“ in it will be slightly different from that in „Ich habe vor, die Hausaufgaben zu machen.“, so I do not think that the problem you describe is severe here.
Still it reminded me of „Lass die Nacht doch rein
aus Vorsicht mal nicht rein“ ;)  (Die Nacht, Wir sind Helden)

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: It took me about 4 seconds to understand the Nacht-line which is fine for a word play but annoying when just due to bad style. When sung or said things might be easier but in writing pronunciation is of no help. Also, if someone had to read out aloud the sentence in question he or she would most certainly stumble at that very point if the text is new to the reader. I stand by my statement but I gave you +1 anyway so now everyone can decide for themselves how "wrong" it really is :)

Comment: The line from „die Nacht“ does is of course meant humoristically. I did not mention it to make a point, it just came to my mind.